# Match partial folder name in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to match part of the folder name with the code below, but I get this message:

> Run-time error "52":
>   Bad file name or number.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub folderButton_Click()

   Dim folderName As String
   Dim folderfullPath As String

   folderName = Me.FormID

   folderfullPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\"

    MsgBox Dir(folderfullPath & "\folders\" & folderName & "*", vbDirectory)

End Sub
```

Using wildcards in the above examples does not work even after setting the second varaible to vbDirectory.

Is there any other way to match part of the folder name in VBA code?

Comment: Are you trying to use this to do or search? or what your you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You have two consecutive  \  in your path. `fullFolderPath` already has a terminating backslash.

Comment: @Kairan I am trying to locate the folder and open it. The folder name would include the formID and other number and letters.

Comment: @TimWilliams the termianting backslash is not an issue. It is only when I use the wildcard "*" I get this error.

Comment: What's the exact value of `Me.FormID` when you get the error ?  Are you sure it doesn't contain a carriage return or line feed for example?

Comment: Typically it would be two letters an two numbers, like: AA51

Comment: Can you provide an actual example which gives you the error?  Also worth trying a debug.print of the full path you're testing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I have written the error code that I get in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `*.*` as a wildcard, like this:

```
Dir(folderfullPath & "\folders\" & folderName & "*.*", vbDirectory)
```

Comment: I have just tried it in my Access. Are you sure that `folderfullPath & "\folders\" & folderName ` is a valid path?

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked the code again and it worked fine. The problem was a trail slash at the end of folderName. I removed it from the code and it worked perfectly.