# VBA Access Get File Name with wildcard

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having a little trouble getting a filename using a wildcard.
I'm using a wildcard because the filename has a "version" in it so in this case "Test v*" could be "Test v1" or "Test v2" because of this I want it to pull the name of whatever version is currently on the desktop.

Here is a simplistic version of my code. if ran you get "Test v*" rather than the actual file name. Not sure what I'm missing but any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Dim Owner As String
Dim Cver As String
Dim FileName As String

Owner = Environ("USERNAME")
FileName = "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\TEST v" & "*" & ".accdb"
Cver = Left(FileName, InStr(FileName, ".") - 1)

MsgBox "" & Mid(Cver, 7, 2) & ""
```

Comment: Use the `Dir`-function to get the exact name, it can handle wildcards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match partial folder name in Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255470/match-partial-folder-name-in-access-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to want to use Dir()

Here is my version of your code:

```
Sub getVersion()

    Dim owner As String
    Dim Cver As String
    Dim fileName As String

    Dim owner As String: owner = Environ("USERNAME")

    Dim fileName As Variant: fileName = Dir("C:\Users\" & owner & "\Desktop\TEST v" & "*" & ".accdb", vbDirectory)

    Cver = Left(fileName, InStr(fileName, ".") - 1)

    MsgBox "" & Mid(Cver, 7, 2) & ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect. Appreciate the help!